# Saving min/max value of noUISlider to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

boyz I wonder if it's possible to get the min/max value and store them to a variable which I can use later? To be more specific I need a global variable(?) of min/max value. So I can use it out of scope. The second problem is that I need to have access to it, without updating the slider. I mean I want for example console.log the actual value of the slider has without moving the slider at all.
Can anyone help?
Something like I did here: https://codepen.io/Hatchling/pen/eRaELE
But I wanna do it with the slider down below.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
 start: [20, 80],
 connect: true,
 range: {
  'min': 0,
  'max': 100
 }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.js"></script>



<div id="slider">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if it's possible to get the min/max value and store them to a variable which I can use later? To be more specific I need a global variable(?) of min/max value. So I can use it out of scope.

I'm not sure how to interpret this question. If you're asking "how to declare a global variable", that's a bit outside the scope of this site--read up on JavaScript scoping rules.

If you're asking, "how to access and/or modify the current values of 'range' after the slider has been created" then you should be able to use the [`options` property](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/) for reading, and the [`updateOptions` method](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/) for setting.

Note that although the docs do say that the `slider.noUiSlider.options` property should return a reference to the options object, I am unable to validate that behavior. If this is necessary your use case, then you might need to engage the noUiSlider maintainers directly with an issue or question.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
 start: [20, 80],
 connect: true,
 range: {
  'min': 0,
  'max': 100
 }
});

$("#getOptionsValue").click(function () {
  var sliderOptions = slider.noUiSlider.options;
  console.log("sliderOptions: ", sliderOptions);
});

$("#updateOptionsValue").click(function() {
  slider.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
    range: {
      min: 10,
      max: 500
    }
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.js"></script>



<div id="slider">

</div>

<button id="getOptionsValue">Get Slider Options (Broken?)</button>
<br/>
<button id="updateOptionsValue">Update Range to 10, 500</button>
```

> The second problem is that I need to have access to it, without updating the slider. I mean I want for example console.log the actual value of the slider has without moving the slider at all.

Does the [`get method`](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/) not satisfy that?

```js
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
 start: [20, 80],
 connect: true,
 range: {
  'min': 0,
  'max': 100
 }
});

$("#getSliderValue").click(function () {
  var sliderValue = slider.noUiSlider.get()
  console.log("sliderValue: ", sliderValue);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.js"></script>



<div id="slider">

</div>

<button id="getSliderValue">Get Slider Value</button>
```

Comment: This one is actually what I was looking for, but is it possible to get min/max value separately as 2 variables.

Comment: That would be set with your options during creation, so you'll have to figure out how to properly use `slider.noUiSlider.options`, or set the options object globally, and inspect it. If you update the slider option, update the global object as well so they stay in sync.

Comment: Well, im kinda new to this, and not familiar with js/jquery so far, but I'll try. :/

Comment: Oh wait, it returns start values >_<

Comment: Okay, I've fixed it. Now I wonder how do I save the value of slider and set it after page reload? Local storage I guess? But I need some help with it for sure. :/